# What is the password of localhost on Windows 7? (SSH related)

Tags: ssh, cygwin

[image]

How to deal with this? I'm using Windows 7, installed SSH via Cygwin.

Comment: To be clear, localhost is a name for your computer.  It doesn't have a password.  What you're looking for is the password for the "Andew" account *on* your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be your windows password

http://home.comcast.net/~3rdshift/articles/cygwin_notes.html

Comment: I don't have a windows password

Comment: Try creating one and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure your host machine to run ssh. Windows doesnt, by default, has a ssh service running. You need to set-up and run a ssh daemon service.

Follow this article:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm

Comment: While the link might provide the answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link in your answer. Thanks.